# Unresponsive form submit button in my CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to get to know CodeIgniter. I just couldn’t figure out what the problem with the code below is. However, when I click on the ‘submit’ button, nothing happens. I mean no record is inserted in the database table. 
The php in the view is as follows.

```
<?php echo form_open('site/create'); ?>
<?php echo form_close();?>
<p> 
<label for="title">Title</label>
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="content">Content</label>
<input type="text" name="content" id="content" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</p>
```

Down goes the controller

```
<?php
class site extends CI_Controller
{
    function index()
{
    $this->load->view('options_view');
}
function create()
 {
        $rec=array(
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'content'=>$this->input->post('content')
        );
        $this->site_model->add_record($rec);
        $this->index();
 }

}
```

?>

And the model is as follows.

```
<?php
class site_model extends CI_Model
{
    function get_records()
    {
        $query=$this->db->get('other');
        return $query->result();
    }
    function add_record($rec)
    {
        $this->db->insert('other',$rec);
        return;
    }
    function update_record($rec)
    {
        $this->db->where('id',2);
        $this->db->update('other',$rec);
    }
    function delete_rec()
    {
        $this->db-delete();
    }
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

The form close has to be at the end:

```
<?php echo form_open('site/create'); ?>
<p> 
<label for="title">Title</label>
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="content">Content</label>
<input type="text" name="content" id="content" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</p>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

It's better and easier to use the form library from codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must be familiar with Html already to start using codeIgniter so this should be easy... Like all html forms you need to have an opening tag and a closing tag, what you have done is open and close the form at the top before the other elements. So as expected, the submit button wont do what you need it to do. The solution is to move 
    `<?php echo form_close();?>` 
to the bottom so your code appears as such 
    `<?php echo form_open('site/create'); ?>
    <p> 
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" />
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="content">Content</label>
    <input type="text" name="content" id="content" />
    </p>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </p>
    <?php echo form_close();?>`

All the best.